# Parallel Computing of dependent for loop in MATLAB

Tags: loops, matlab, for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing

currently, I am using a nested for loop to calculate a finite difference scheme. The array that is calculated is dependent both, on the array values of the previous iteration of the outer loop and the neighboring values inside the array.

```
for l=2:timesteps         %start time loop
    
    %now calculate new concentration values for the current timestep
    for k=2:nodes-1         %start spatial loop over inner nodes
        conc(k,l)=conc(k,l-1)+(r*(conc(k-1,l-1)-(2*conc(k,l-1))+conc(k+1,l-1)));
    end                   %end spatial loop over inner nodes
    
    %calculate boundary nodes
    conc(1,l)= c_surface;
    conc(nodes,l)=conc(nodes)+(r*((2*conc(nodes-1))-(2*conc(nodes))));
      
end                      %end time loop
```

I would like a way to optimize the code for parallel computing.

I tried using the parfor feature but I have realized that this does not work for dependent loops. I understand that the workload is divided and sent to the workers, who do not communicate. This is the reason why parfor does not work. I wonder if there is an alternative.

Comment: By definition, if one iteration is dependent on the previous one completing then it is impossible to compute them in parallel. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] then it might be possible to speed up your code without parallelisation, but we can't know from the code you've included

Comment: The alternative is learning A LOT about prallel computing, shared memory, thread signals etc. So there is an alternative, but I'd say it requires you to read at least one book on parallel computing

Comment: It looks like your inner loop is a plain old convolution. Use `conv`, which uses all of your cores automatically if it’s worth it (ie the inputs are large enough). The outer loop is sequential by definition and cannot be parallelized.